# How to get variables of a constraint in Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

In Pyomo, how can I get a list of the variables appearing in a constraint?

I combed through the code in Github, but could not a find any suitable method or attribute for that purpose.

Comment: I don't know why you want to downvote my question, but please let me know why and maybe I can clarify it if you missed something.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself: `model.con1.body._args` gets you the desired list.

Comment: This is not the best answer.  See the answer in the duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48538945/access-all-variables-occurring-in-a-pyomo-constraint