# Access all variables occurring in a pyomo constraint

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

I am working on an algorithm in python that needs to modify concrete (mixed-integer nonlinear) pyomo models. 
In particular, I need to know which variables are present in a **general algebraic constraint**.
E.g. for a constraint

`model.con1 = Constraint(expr=exp(model.x_1) + 2*model.x_2 <= 2)`

I would like to make a a query (like `model.con1.variables` ) which returns (a list of) the variables (`[model.x_1,model.x_2]`).

In [this documentation](http://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library_reference/kernel/constraint.html) I find that for **linear** constraints, the parameter `variables` exactly serves my purpose. However, the models I'm working with will also contain general algebraic constraints.

[Chapter 14 of this book](http://www.springer.com/de/book/9783319588193) provides several details for the development of high-level algorithms using pyomo, but I did not find an answer to my question there. The only very clumsy approach I can think of is to use the to_string() method of the expression (returning `exp( x_1 ) + x_2  <=  1.0` in our example), and then to search this string for the appearence of all variables. I'm sure there is a much better way using pyomo to access the variables occurring in a constraint.

Note that a similar, but less detailed and unanswered question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519905/how-to-get-variables-of-a-constraint-in-pyomo).

Comment: The link you provide for linear constraints only applies to the `kernel` interface.  That interface is a specialized, low-level programming API that has been proposed for efficiently generating models in a programmatic context.  At the moment (as of Pyomo 5.3), it does not necessarily apply to "normal" Pyomo models.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not want to directly query the `_args` attribute of the expression returned by `model.con1.body`.  Methods and attributes beginning with an underscore are considered *private* and should not be used by general users (they are undocumented and subject to change with no notice or deprecation warning).  Second, the `_args` attribute only returns the children of that node in the expression tree.  For linear expressions, there is a high probability that those are the variables, but it is not guaranteed.  For nonlinear expressions (and general expressions), the members of `_args` are almost guaranteed to be other expression objects.

You can get the variables that appear in any Pyomo expression using the `identify_variables` generator:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.core.base.expr import identify_variables

m = ConcreteModel()
m.x_1 = Var()
m.x_2 = Var()
m.c = Constraint(expr=exp(model.x_1) + 2*model.x_2 <= 2)
vars = list(identify_variables(m.c.body))
```

Comment: Note that for pyomo version 6.x, the import statement would be like:
```from pyomo.core.expr.current import identify_variables```

Answer (score 0):

`model.con1.body._args` gives you just this list of variables.

Comment: There is a pending expression system revamp that may cause such usage to no longer behave as expected.