# Get coefficients of a linear pyomo constraint

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

I would like to obtain the coefficients of a linear constraint `c` of a pyomo model `m`.

For instance, for

```
    m= ConcreteModel()
    m.x_1 = Var()
    m.x_2 = Var()
    m.x_3 = Var(within = Integers)
    m.x_4 = Var(within = Integers)
    m.c= Constraint(expr=2*m.x_1 + 5*m.x_2 + m.x_4 <= 2)
```

I would like to get the array `c_coef = [2,5,0,1]`.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48538945/access-all-variables-occurring-in-a-pyomo-constraint)  explains how to obtain all variables occurring in a linear constraint and I can easily use this to create the zero-coefficients for variables which don't occur in a constraint. However, I am struggling with the nonzero-coefficients. My current approach uses the *private* attribute `_coef`, that is `c_nzcoef = m.c.body._coef` which I probably should not use.

What would be the proper way to obtain the nonzero coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get the coefficients for a linear expression is to make use of the "Canonical Representation" data structure:

```
from pyomo.repn import generate_canonical_repn
# verify that the expression is linear
if m.c.body.polynominal_degree() == 1:
    repn = generate_canonical_repn(m.c.body)
    for i, coefficient in enumerate(repn.linear or []):
        var = repn.variables[i]
```

This should be valid for any version of Pyomo from 4.0 through at least 5.3.

Comment: How about newer versions of Pyomo (I would like to make use of numerical derivatives which seems to be available in newer pyomo versions)? When I update, it seems that I also have to replace `identify variables` and `clone_expression`. If this is too much to add to your post, I can also post a separate question.