# Get coefficients of a polynomial pyomo constraint

Tags: python, pyomo

In addition to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48749651/get-coefficients-of-a-linear-pyomo-constraint) I would like to know how to obtain the coefficients of an arbitrary polynomial constraint of a pyomo model. So, for

```
m= ConcreteModel()
m.x_1 = Var()
m.x_2 = Var()
m.x_3 = Var(within = Integers)
m.x_4 = Var(within = Integers)
m.c= Constraint(expr=2*m.x_1**2 + 5*m.x_1*m.x_2 + m.x_4 <= 2)
```

I would like to have

```
coeff[c] = [2, 5, 1].
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no easy way to do this without walking the expression tree for arbitrary polynomials (since you could have `(x-3)^2+5x+6`).

One approach  could be to `sympy`-ify the pyomo expression and ask sympy for those values: [How to extract all coefficients in sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955888/how-to-extract-all-coefficients-in-sympy)

The current implementation of differentiate actually makes use of sympy: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/4997726dd1f11bdb86589ff1c2f4badc654a69ad/pyomo/core/base/symbolic.py#L128