# How to get all variables in a constraint in Pyomo?

Tags: pyomo

My question is simple. Given a Pyomo constraint, how can I easily extract the variables that appear in the constraint?

This question has been asked a few times already. I believe the Pyomo internals have been modified and the proposed solutions no longer work.

[How to get variables of a constraint in Pyomo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519905/how-to-get-variables-of-a-constraint-in-pyomo)

[Access all variables occurring in a pyomo constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48538945/access-all-variables-occurring-in-a-pyomo-constraint)

Minimum working test problem:

```
from pyomo.environ import *

m = ConcreteModel()

m.I = Set(initialize=[i for i in range(5)])

m.x = Var(m.I,bounds=(-10,10),initialize=1.0)
m.z = Var(bounds=(-100,100), initialize=5.0)

m.con1 = Constraint(expr=m.x[0] + m.x[1] - m.x[3] >= 10)
m.con2 = Constraint(expr=m.x[0]*m.x[3] + m.x[1] >= 0)
m.con3 = Constraint(expr=m.x[4]*m.x[3] + m.x[0]*m.x[3] - m.x[4] == 0)

m.obj = Objective(expr=sum(m.x[i]**2 for i in m.I))

m.pprint()

opt = SolverFactory('ipopt')
opt.options['max_iter'] = 0
opt.solve(m, tee=True)
```

In this example, I would like to programmatically inspect the variables in `con1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second link has the correct solution: [Access all variables occurring in a pyomo constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48538945/access-all-variables-occurring-in-a-pyomo-constraint)

`identify_variables()` still exists, but it looks like it was moved to `pyomo.core.expr.visitor`.
It might be worth promoting it into the `pyomo.core.expr` namespace.